# C# Datetimes: Conversion for different time zones

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have a bunch of date times that I keep track of for my app. They are all in UTC time. For part of my app I want to send an email with one of these times, but edited to be in that specific time zone.

There are only two major areas that I will deal with, the east coast and Texas (Dallas and Huston)

I can also make a new datetime when I send out this email to get the eastern time zone (`DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;`)

**My Question is this:**

If the user is in the texas area how can I convert my time from eastern to that time (1 hour less)?

I tried something like this:

```
            //Convert timestamp to local time
            TimeSpan ts = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(timestamp);
            timestamp.Add(ts);

            timestampString = timestamp.ToString();
```

But that didn't work. I also know that this line is not valid:

```
timestamp.Hour = timestamp.Hour - 1;
```

Comment: You should avoid DateTime.Now, and instead use DateTime.UtcNow.  DateTime.Now may suprise you one day, with either the wrong time zone, or the wrong daylight savings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx) Class to convert a local time to a time in an alternative timezone:

```
TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(timeToConvert, est);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    var now = DateTime.Now; // Current date/time
    var utcNow = now.ToUniversalTime(); // Converted utc time
    var otherTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("ANY OTHER VALID TIMEZONE"); // Get other timezone
    var newTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcNow, otherTimezone); // New Timezone
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx). The example listed there is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript:

```
 var visitortime = new Date();
    vat time = visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

After that you can save this value to any hidden control which is runat ="server".

Answer (score 0):

why not just

`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "AUS Eastern Standard Time");`

and check get all available timezones

```
foreach (TimeZoneInfo tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine(tz.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string IST_DATE(DateTime date)
    {
        if (date != null)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc((DateTime)date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        }
        return "";

    }
```

Comment: Datetimes are structs which cannot be null. You are also casting date to DateTime but it is already declared as Datetime.