# Convert EST time to local time

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, timezone

I am new to C#

I am using YQL to obtain data in XML format.

i receive a time in such 10:47PM EST

i want to convert it to my time zone, let's say convert to CST (China Standard Time) or MYT (Malaysia Standard Time)

how do i convert using asp.net C#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682290/c-sharp-datetimes-conversion-for-different-time-zones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try **TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime** method:

```
DateTime estTime = new DateTime(); //for example: 10:47PM EST

TimeZoneInfo estZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("China Standard Time");

DateTime yourLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(estTime, estZone, cstZone);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the time in desired zone.
Try this

```
string ClientTime = ConvertDatebyUserTimezone(UserTimeZone, dateToConvert).ToString();

public DateTime ConvertDatebyUserTimezone(string UserTimezone, DateTime SrcDate)
{
    DateTime Returndate = SrcDate;                
    TimeZoneInfo Serverzone = null;
    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
    foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in timeZones)
    {
       if (timeZoneInfo.ToString().Contains(ToConvertTimezone))
       {
          Serverzone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneInfo.Id);
          break;
       }
    }
    if (UserTimezone != "")
    {
        foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in timeZones)
        {
            if (timeZoneInfo.ToString().Contains(UserTimezone))
            {
                TimeZoneInfo timez = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneInfo.Id);
                Returndate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(SrcDate, ToConvertTimezone, timez);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return Returndate;
}
```

This will help you..