# How to get DateTime from UTC offset

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to figure out how to get a `DateTime` instance using an UTC offset value, i have to get the `DateTime` of the desired UTC offset regardless of which UTC the current system is.

All posts i've seen are about getting the UTC string data from a `DateTime`, also i've seen that there is a post that says how to get the other `DateTime` by calculating the difference using the current `DateTime`, that doesn't seem to work well since i need the code to be working regardless of which UTC the system is using.

What i have tried this far:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    TimeSpan offSet = TimeSpan.FromHours((double)-4.00); // UTC-4
    DateTime newDateTime = utcDateTime.Add(offSet);

    Console.WriteLine(newDateTime);
}
```

This is something i saw in a different post but it looks that it only changes the hour in a wrong way.. please help.

Comment: Why not use `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: “regardless of which UTC the system is using.” - there is only one UTC.

Comment: `...regardless of which UTC the system is using` - Your question doesn't make sense. There is only `one` UTC. Are you confusing time zones with UTC?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? I might not understand the problem entirely.             var time = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-4);

Comment: Can you provide some concrete examples? The question doesn't make much sense as-is.

Comment: @Dai i mean that the system might be using `utc-3` in one client, and it could be using `utc-6` in another client

Comment: what i need is to get what is the datetime in a given utc offset

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682290/c-sharp-datetimes-conversion-for-different-time-zones)

Comment: @John, that doesn't help because i am making use of `AWS` regions, and because of daylight savings the AWS region server changes the UTC offset, i can make code to handle the daylight savings, but i still need to know the datetime for a given UTC offset

Comment: What output do you expect from the above code? Any AwS server will have time zone set to UTC.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i have to sign the request for the AWS manually, and using the SDK is not an option since the SDK for the platform i am using does not support the service i need to work on

Comment: Why not sign the request with UTC? :/

Comment: @John the request is signed, and all the code works fine if the system is using the same UTC offset as the AWS server, but it fails when the system is using a different UTC offset.. hence why i am looking for a way to get the datetime from a given UTC offset

Comment: Remind me again why you can't use `TimeZoneInfo` to convert to the server time? Surely you know the timezone in a given region?

Comment: @John i once tried using `TimeZoneInfo` but i failed to even make it work since i don't know the api well, i was suggested to use a timezone id, but i don't think that could work since i don't know what id the AWS server regions use

Comment: Surely you can find out from the machine in question? I'd advise opening a new question (since this already has two good answers as it is in its current state, and changing the question now in such a tangential would be very questionable, IMHO). In the new question, show how you're making the request, what service you're making the request to, etc. We're signing requests for an S3 bucket (because the SDK doesn't support signing multipart URLs) and it's working fine using UTC timestamps.

Comment: @OscarReyes - The AWS region is irrelevant.  The server's time zone setting is also irrelevant when you call `DateTime.UtcNow`.  Only the current UTC time applies, which is the same *everywhere* as long as the server's clocks are correctly synchronized.  AWS should be doing that for you automatically.  If the whole point of this question was to try to counteract time zone effects of the server's location, then that original premise is faulty.  Just use UTC time, and only worry about time zone conversion when you're displaying data for a particular user or at a particular location.

Comment: @MattJohnson - the timezone of the server is relevant because i have to sign the request with the datetime to be the same (with 5 mins tolerance) as the server, otherwise the server will just deny the request.. all i need is to get a datetime to be in the same UTC as the server

Comment: Nvm, i didn't read the part of how to handle the date in signing for amazon, the date still must be in UTC but without an offset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the current time in a particular offset (such as UTC-4), as a `DateTime`, the easiest way (IMHO) is:

```
DateTime dt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(-4)).DateTime;
```

Another (messier) way to get the same results would be:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-4), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

One might also just keep it as a `DateTimeOffset`, such that the offset from UTC is not lost.

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(-4));
```

Or the messier way:

```
TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromHours(-4);
DateTime dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow.Add(offset), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
```

However, in most cases, one is probably not working with a fixed offset, but is instead looking for the time in a particular time zone, which could be in a variety of different offsets depending on the date in question, due to both daylight saving time and changes in the standard time observed by a particular government.

See also  "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

In .NET, the `TimeZoneInfo` class can manage such changes for you.  On Windows, it uses Microsoft time zone identifiers, and on Linux or Mac OSX, it uses IANA time zone identifiers.  For example:

```
// On Windows:
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, tz);

// On Linux/OSX:
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");
DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, tz);
```

In both examples, the correct UTC offset (either UTC-5 for EST or UTC-4 for EDT) will be applied.

These could also be written using `DateTimeOffset` values:

```
// On Windows:
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset dto = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tz);

// On Linux/OSX:
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");
DateTimeOffset dto = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tz);
```

Additionally, if you need to write code that can run on either platform, you can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library to work with either set of identifiers on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

Why all of you give so complex answers?

Is this wrong?

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-4); //UTC-4
```

Comment: It's wrong because the resulting value would have its `Kind` property still at `DateTimeKind.Utc`, which could cause other APIs to produce incorrect results when passed this value as input (ex: serialization, time zone conversion, etc.).

Comment: I updated my answer to show what you'd have to do next to take this approach.

Comment: Do you mean some APIs can not handle the kind flag correctly?

Comment: All the built-in apis will honor the kind flag correctly.  If you tell it UTC, it will believe you mean UTC.  If you mean something else, like UTC-4, it won't know that.